# SQL Server 2008 Linked Server and CONTEXT_INFO

Tags: sql-server-2008, linked-server, change-tracking

I'm trying to use the SQL Server 2008 Change Tracking feature. Once the feature is enabled, you can make use of the `CHANGETABLE(...` function to query the change tracking history that is kept internally by SQL Server, e.g.:

```
SELECT
CT.ID, CT.SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION,
CT.SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS, CT.SYS_CHANGE_CONTEXT
FROM
CHANGETABLE(CHANGES dbo.CONTACT,20) AS CT
```

where the SYS_CHANGE_CONTEXT  column records the `CONTEXT_INFO()` session value.  This column is useful for auditing who changed what etc.

Some of the statements that change data are executed using four-part notation by a remote SQL Server that has the home server as a linked server e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO [home server].[db name].[dbo].[CONTACT](id) values(@id)
```

My problem is that the CONTEXT_INFO() as set on the remote server in the session executing the query does not get picked up in my home server change tracking, i.e. it doesn't look like the CONTEXT_INFO spans a distributed query.  This means that the following will **not** result in the CONTEXT_INFO being logged on the home server change tracking.

```
-- I'm running on a remote server
WITH CHANGE_TRACKING_CONTEXT (0x1256698477) 
INSERT INTO [home server].[db name].[dbo].[CONTACT](id) values(@id)
```

Does anyone know whether this is a limitation or if there is a way to persist/communicate CONTEXT_INFO across the distributed query?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about using Context_Info to audit changes (web app). but after doing some tests understood its not good idea. Because of connection pooling context_info was not working the way i desired.

Ended up with using GUID identifier associated with each logical session + table, where is stored session GUID and information related to session + each table stores that identifier in separate column. Not as easy to code as it would be with context_info()..

And as far as i understood from documentation, change tracking is not designed for audit purposes (think that is what you trying to do).